# asp.net : set default value selected for a drop down list

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

is there any method to set the default value selected for a drop down list (asp.net C#), by JavaScript function ? thanks.

Comment: Why not set the default selected item on the server side when you build the select list?

Comment: i want to select a value from table or DB cell then set it as default value.

Answer (score 0):

**Use server side**

```
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = wantedIndex; // ex 0
```

Or you could check my Javascript example : http://jsfiddle.net/wqzdpjmw/2/

Comment: by javascript not C#, is there anyway?

Comment: There is a. Is there any reasons why you wanna javascript one, not the C# ?

Comment: i want to select a value from table cell or Database then set it as default value. the dropdownlist must be fill on load.

Comment: i get the value from data base by handler.ashx and json data.

Comment: Check my jsfiddle example, thats the way you could do it.